# What is the correct .Net method to decrypt an android AES encrypted file

Tags: java, android, vb.net, encryption

I have encrypted a zip file in android using this method:

```
String s_InitKey = "1612211310164660";
String s_IvSpec = "MySecreteBytes00";

IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(s_IvSpec.getBytes("UTF-8"));
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(s_InitKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
```

I need to decrypt the file using windows, I have tried the following method:

```
    Private Sub LicenceEncryptOrDecrypt(LizenzDatei As String, EncryptOrDecrypt As String)

        Dim Rijndael As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged

        Dim passPhrase As String = "SuperPassword"
        Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1"
        Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 3
        Dim keySize As Integer = 128

        Dim initVector As String = "16charLongString"
        Rijndael.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

        Dim saltValue As String = "DoYouWantSomeSalt"
        Dim saltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

        Dim password As Rfc2898DeriveBytes = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes)

        Rijndael.Key = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)

        Rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None


        Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
        Dim tempFile As String


        Select Case EncryptOrDecrypt
            Case "Encrypt"
                transform = Rijndael.CreateEncryptor(Rijndael.Key, Rijndael.IV)
                tempFile = LizenzDatei + ".enc"
            Case "Decrypt"
                transform = Rijndael.CreateDecryptor(Rijndael.Key, Rijndael.IV)
                tempFile = LizenzDatei + ".dec"
            Case Else
                Debug.Print(">< EncryptOrDecrypt: Falshes parameter. Ende Sub.")
                Success = False
        End Select


        Using inFS As FileStream = New FileStream(LizenzDatei, FileMode.Open)
            Dim data() As Byte = New Byte(inFS.Length - 1) {}

            Using outFS As FileStream = New FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create)
                Using outStreamEncrypted As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outFS, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                    outStreamEncrypted.FlushFinalBlock()
                    outStreamEncrypted.Close()
                End Using
                outFS.Close()
            End Using
            inFS.Close()
        End Using

        File.Delete(LizenzDatei)
        File.Move(tempFile, LizenzDatei)

    End Sub
```

I am generating the zip file in android then I export it to a folder in the android sub system.  From there I copy it over to windows and it is here that I need to decrypt the file.

**EDIT - Modified VB Code**

```
Private Sub LicenceEncryptOrDecrypt(EncryptedFile As SimpleFile, Direction As CryptoAction)
        Dim Rijndael As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged

        Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "AES"

        Rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None

        Dim s_Temp As String = EncryptedFile.Name.Substring(9, EncryptedFile.Name.Length - 9)
        Dim c_Date As New SimpleDate(s_Temp)
        'c_Date.getKey translates 16bit key'
        Dim Key As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c_Date.getKey)
        Dim IV As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecreteBytes00")

        Rijndael.IV = IV
        Rijndael.Key = Key


        Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
        Dim tempFile As String


        Select Case Direction
            Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                transform = Rijndael.CreateEncryptor(Rijndael.Key, Rijndael.IV)
                tempFile = EncryptedFile.FullPath
            Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                transform = Rijndael.CreateDecryptor(Rijndael.Key, Rijndael.IV)
                tempFile = EncryptedFile.Path + "\" + EncryptedFile.Name + ".zip""
        End Select

        Dim data() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(EncryptedFile.FullPath)

        Using outFS As FileStream = New FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create)
            Using outStreamEncrypted As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outFS, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                outStreamEncrypted.FlushFinalBlock()
                outStreamEncrypted.Close()
            End Using
            outFS.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Why are you specifying `PaddingMode.None`? 2. Have you verified via a hex dump the key is the same? 3. I assume that in reality the iv is the same. 4. Have you tried with a small file, say 40 bytes? 5. For both the encryption and decryption please provide in hex the key, iv, input data and output data.

Comment: Where are the details of how `SecretKeySpec` works? Is it really Rfc2898DeriveBytes? `hashAlgorithm` and `passwordIterations` are never used.

Comment: when I run the code without the `PaddingMode` then I receive a `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.` error.
The `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is of no concern, i removed it and relpaced it with a simpler key method for testing.

I have not tested the raw bytes encryption yet.
I have also removed hashAlgorithm

I will update the code to show my modifications.

Comment: Thank you zaph, I added both mode and padding to the encrypting functions, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use padding unless the data is always a multiple of the block size. You need to use the same padding mode for both encryption and decryption.

Removing non-essential code in test cases is best.

If you want to verify the encryption ad decryption you can use the online AES service by Cryptomathic.